# Invocation.Builder java how to post json as a string not an Entity

Tags: java, json

Using the Invocation Builder in Java, the only options for put/post are an Entity as the object it gets it json from:

```
    public <T> T put(final Entity<?> entity, final Class<T> responseType)
```

If you already have the json in a string, is there any way to put/post this without having to convert it into an Entity (which we assume is just an object)

```
String payload = "{\"name\":\"hello\"}";

WebTarget webTarget = theHttpClient.target(url);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(HttpUtils.AUTHORISATION_HEADER_NAME, "Bearer " + theAccessToken); 

// this outputs the string with slashes, i.e. "{\n\"name\":\"hello\"\n}"; instead of {"name":"hello"}
invocationBuilder.put( Entity.json(theObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload)), responseClass);

// this will not compile as payload is not an Entity
invocationBuilder.put(payload, responseClass);
```

Comment: Maybe you could parse the string into an ObjectNode with ObjectMapper from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind and give the ObjectNode as an entity. You wouldn't have to implement a model class, just add a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a quick test, and i think you error comes from you calling the object mapper directly here

> `Entity.json(theObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload))`

From a quick test, if you simply pass the payload string without calling the object mapper, it seems to work

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

testInvocationBuilder.java

```
public class testInvocationBuilder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://127.0.0.1:8000");

        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Payload p = new Payload();
        p.name = "hello-there";

        //this serializes the object in the request
        Response payloadRsp = invocationBuilder.put(Entity.entity(p, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        System.out.println(payloadRsp);

        //this seems to pass through
        String payload = "{\"name\":\"hello\"}";
        Response stringRsp = invocationBuilder.put(Entity.entity(payload, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        System.out.println(stringRsp);
    }

    public static class Payload {
        public String name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. The missing piece for me was how to create an entity form a string, as entity object is a mystery, even after looking through as many examples with it as I could find.